# python how to turn values into columns

Tags: python-3.x

I have below python list

```
[[User1, LocationA, V1, V2, V3..],
 [User2, LocationB, V1,V2, V3..],
 [User3, LocationA, V1, V2, V3..],
 [User4, LocationC, V1, V2, V3..],
 [USer5, LocationC, V1, V2, V3..],
 [USer6, LocationD, V1, V2, V3..]]
```

I want to turn this into something like

```
[[User1, 1,0,0,0, V1, V2, V3..],
 [User2, 0,1,0,0, V1,V2, V3..],
 [User3, 1,0,0,0, V1, V2, V3..],
 [User4, 0,0,1,0, V1, V2, V3..],
 [USer5, 0,0,1,0, V1, V2, V3..],
 [USer6, 0,0,0,1, V1, V2, V3..]]
```

where each of the unique location get represented by a new list element, in which 1 indicate that user is in that location and 0 indicate user is not in that location.

How do I do that in python?

Comment: Please clarify what you're trying to do and add the actual input, desired output and what you've tried.

Comment: input is the first list and output is the second list. Basically I want to turn the location data in the first list into binary value(0 or 1), with each of the locations represented, if user belongs to the location, the value is 1 otherwise the value is 0

Comment: I meant what are the `Location` variables? Lists of 0s and 1s or any other objects?

Comment: Location means "Seattle", "San Francisco", "New York", "Chicago"..

Comment: So if the user is in Seattle it should replace it with `1, 0, 0, 0`, if he's in San Francisco `0, 1, 0, 0` and so on?

Comment: Do you use Python version 3.5 or 3.6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a dictionary that maps the cities/locations to the number tuples and then iterate over the original data and replace the city names with the numbers by unpacking them with the star operator `*`.

```
data = [
    ['User1', 'Seattle', 'V1', 'V2', 'V3'],
    ['User2', 'San Francisco', 'V1', 'V2', 'V3'],
    ['User3', 'New York', 'V1', 'V2', 'V3'],
    ['User4', 'Chicago', 'V1', 'V2', 'V3'],
    ]

# Create a dictionary that maps the cities to the numbers.
city_codes = {
    'Seattle': (1, 0, 0, 0),
    'San Francisco': (0, 1, 0, 0),
    'New York': (0, 0, 1, 0),
    'Chicago': (0, 0, 0, 1),
    }

# Create a new list.
changed_data = []
# Unpack the data.
for user, city, *rest in data:
    # Now append new sublists. Get the codes out of the dict
    # and unpack them into the list and also unpack the rest
    # of the list items. (You can only use multiple * asterisks
    # for the unpacking in Python 3.5 and above.)
    changed_data.append([user, *city_codes[city], *rest])


# Same as above as a nested list comprehension.
# changed_data = [[user, *city_codes[city], *rest]
#                 for user, city, *rest in data]
```

Comment: Thanks Skrx. This assumes I know the list of location ahead of times, but in reality I don't. The location string could be any city that I don't know ahead of times..

Comment: Do you mean the locations in the `data` list or which city is related to a specific number code (in the dictionary)? Explain a bit more detailed how you get the input and how the program should work.

Comment: Yes, I meant the locations in the data list are not known in design time.. think about user registration where they specify the city they live in, I don't know all the values ahead of times. But once I get a batch of result data, I'd want to find out the unique list of location value, and turn them into the dictionary that you created above (but alphabetically so I know the order) and with 1 represent user's matching location and 0 for the rest, exactly as you did in design time above.

Comment: So you get the cities from the users, then sort them alphabetically and create the city dict with the corresponding numbers? If the users can enter new cities during the runtime, the dict and the number codes would keep changing all the time, right? What's your actual goal? What do you want to do with the data?

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
l = [ ['User1', 'LocationA', 'V1', 'V2', 'V3'],
      ['User2', 'LocationB', 'V1', 'V2', 'V3'],
      ['User3', 'LocationA', 'V1', 'V2', 'V3'],
      ['User4', 'LocationC', 'V1', 'V2', 'V3'],
      ['USer5', 'LocationC', 'V1', 'V2', 'V3'],
      ['USer6', 'LocationD', 'V1', 'V2', 'V3'] ]

# get which index to set to '1' for locations in [0,0,0,0] 
indexes = [(ord(x[1][-1].lower())-96)-1 for x in l]

# new list default second element before setting '1'
idx1 = [0,0,0,0]

newl = []

for idx, subl in enumerate(l):
    idx1[indexes[idx]] = 1
    newl.append(l[idx])
    newl[idx][1] = ','.join([str(i) for i in idx1])
    idx1 = [0,0,0,0]

print newl
```

output:

```
[['User1', '1,0,0,0', 'V1', 'V2', 'V3'], 
 ['User2', '0,1,0,0', 'V1', 'V2', 'V3'], 
 ['User3', '1,0,0,0', 'V1', 'V2', 'V3'], 
 ['User4', '0,0,1,0', 'V1', 'V2', 'V3'], 
 ['USer5', '0,0,1,0', 'V1', 'V2', 'V3'], 
 ['USer6', '0,0,0,1', 'V1', 'V2', 'V3']]
```